# UIWebView's "loadData" method does not accept nil for baseURL in Swift 2

Tags: uiwebview, swift2

I don't want to pass any value to baseURL parameter in `loadData` method of `UIWebView`.

In Swift 1.2, `nil` works fine:

```
self.loadFundInfo.loadData(responseData, MIMEType: contentType, textEncodingName: "", baseURL: nil)
```

In Swift 2.0, how to do the same thing?

I am getting this error:

> Nil is not compatible with expected argument type NSURL

Comment: More, details needed, the same should work

Comment: I added more details to it. If you require any more info, please let me know.

Comment: is the data being loaded from the disk?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is rather self-explanatory: the `baseURL` parameter must now be of type `NSURL`, not `NSURL?` (not an optional anymore, so it can not be nil).

Method signature in Swift 2 is:

```
loadData(data: NSData, MIMEType: String, textEncodingName: String, baseURL: NSURL)
```

The answer is *you can't do the same thing, you have to provide a base URL*.

Comment: Yes. But how to pass empty NSURL value in swift 2.0 which can be equivalent of nil in swift 1.2

Comment: **You can't**. This is the answer. You can't set the `baseURL` property to nil anymore, you have to change the way you're doing this. Sure, you could always pass an empty `NSURL()` but what good could it do?