# Can't load Data in a WKWebView with a nil baseUrl in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, wkwebview

I'm trying to load some Data in a WKWebView and the compiler won't let me pass in `nil` nor `URL()` for the baseUrl parameter. Is there a workaround? I don't care at all about a baseUrl.

Below is my code with trying `nil` and then trying `URL()` along with the errors, respectively.

`self.webView.load(data!, mimeType: "image/png", characterEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: nil);`

`error: nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'URL'`

`self.webView.load(data!, mimeType: "image/png", characterEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: URL());`

`error: cannot invoke initializer for type 'URL' with no arguments`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761819/uiwebviews-loaddata-method-does-not-accept-nil-for-baseurl-in-swift-2 (syntax is for Swift 2 but it's the same issue)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you will always need a baseURL.

Just invoke it with `URL(string: "http://localhost")`

Browsers always load from a URL and WKWebView behaves like a browser so it requires some sort of base URL.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13739157)

Comment: Updated with my reasoning